# How to add to a INNER JOIN to pull multiple rows?

Tags: sql

I have the following SQL query:

```
select * from id i
inner join sval s 
on i.id = s.id 
where i.clid = 88 and s.fid = 996 and s.val = 'XLON'
```

At the moment, the above produces one row.

I want to expand this query so that I have `s.fid = 997 and s.fid=998` as 2 additional rows. How would I do this?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Comment: Tag the DBMS you are using

Comment: Your description is unclear. Should the other two conditions also be applied on these two further fid values? Then the answer below will do. Or should they be selected without these conditions? Then add an OR as second option.

Comment: It was clear enough for the answer... the answer works. 

In any case I am using Dbeaver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, the easiest way is to use an IN condition. So you can get results by a List of s.fids.

```
select * from id i 
inner join sval s on i.id = s.id 
where i.clid = 88 and s.val = 'XLON' and s.fid in (996, 997, 998)
```